# Meaning of fourth component of velocity four vector

Tags: special-relativity, velocity

Can any one help me to understand what the fourth component of [velocity four vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity) mean physically?

Comment: We really can't help unless we know what you think about it currently, unless you don't know that it's the time aspect of space-time. What have you read, and what confuses you about what you've read?

Answer (score 2):

Physically, it tells you the direction in spacetime that the object is going. Because it is a unit vector and it points the direction in spacetime the object is going.

Recall how in 3d you can represent the direction of a velocity vector with a unit vector? You could choose any orthonormal basis you like and then the components were $$\left(\frac{v_x}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_y^2}},
\frac{v_y}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_y^2}},
\frac{v_z}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_y^2}}\right).$$

And you could get it by taking $(\Delta x, \Delta y,\Delta z)$ for two points where the particle is at at really close moments in time and then making a unit vector version of it. It just tells you the direction in space it is going. And as a vector it's the same for anyone that measures distance like you do. No matter what basis they use, though with a different 3d basis they get different components.

The four velocity is like that, it's merely a direction in spacetime. And you get it by considering two events $(ct_1,x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(ct_2,x_2,y_2,z_2)$ where the particle is at that are really close together in time and subtracting them to get the vector between them $(c\Delta t,\Delta x, \Delta y,\Delta z)$ and then making a unit vector out of that.

And what's nice here is that every frame agrees on this vector, even if they give different components in a different 4d basis.

So **physically** all it does it tell you the direction in spacetime that an object is going, just like the unit 3 velocity tells you the direction in space something is going.

As an aside if you call $w=ct$ then it is like time but measured in meters and then $(w,x,y,z)$ are the components so having it as a 0th component (rather than a 4th) seems more natural.

Now there is an interesting relationship between energy and momentum and the unit tangent.

$$(E,c\vec p)=mc^2u,$$

Where $u$ is the unit tangent, $\vec p$ is the 3 momentum, $m$ is the rest mass, $E$ is the energy (rest energy and kinetic energy together) and $c$ is the speed of light.

Which means the fourth component is the specific energy (energy per unit mass) except with come factors of $c$ to make it dimension less. And it should be dimensionless since it is a component of a unit vector.

So $E/m$ or $E/mc^2.$

Comment: He asked about the physical meaning of the fourth component, not the whole vector.

Comment: @Physikslover I think if you know what a vector is then you know its components. And that since components depend on a frame that they don't have a physical meaning, but in deference to people that like to think in frame dependent ways, I've edited by adding a bit at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose I am measuring your four-velocity. My coordinates are the usual $(t, x, y, z)$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the distances measured by my rulers and $t$ is the time measured by my clock.

In your coordinate frame, i.e. the frame with you stationary at the origin, we'll call your time coordinate $\tau$, where $\tau$ is also the [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time).

The four-velocity measured in my coordinates is defined as:

$$ \mathbf{u} = \left( \frac{dt}{d\tau}, \frac{dx}{d\tau}, \frac{dy}{d\tau}, \frac{dz}{d\tau} \right) $$

So the four-velocity is the derivative of **my** coordinates with respect to **your** time.

You don't say exactly what you mean by the fourth component of the four-velocity, but I'm guessing you mean $dt/d\tau$ (which we normally put first i.e. $u^0$). This component describes the rate of change of my time with respect to your time, so it's actually just equal to the time dilation factor $\gamma$. If you are stationary with respect to me then $dt/d\tau = 1$ and our clocks tick at the same rate. If you are moving with respect to me then $dt/d\tau \gt 0$ and my clock ticks faster than yours, or conversely your clock ticks slower than mine, by a factor of $dt/d\tau$.

Comment: Am I mixed up something, but if you are measuring Self Made Man's 4-velocity in your frame, then shouldn't the proper time be your proper time instead of his (since you will be measuring the rate of change of his spacetime coordinates as seen in your frame for each tick of your own clock?

Comment: @Secret: No. The proper time is the distance along the worldline of the moving object. In Self Made Man's frame this is simply equal to the time on his clock. In my frame I would have to calculate the proper time $\tau$ using the metric $d\tau^2 = dt^2 - dx^2 - dy^2 - dz^2$. That is if I measure SMM to move a distance ($dx$, $dy$, $dz$) in a time $dt$ then the change in the proper time $d\tau$ is calculated using the metric.

Answer (score 1):

## Lorentz boosts and inner products

First, it helps to know a little bit about relativity: relativity is a slight tweak of our normal understanding of physics, where if I put an infinite grid of clocks around you and carefully desynchronize them so that, from your perspective, you see them all "tick" at the same time and show the same amount no matter how far away they are from you, then when you accelerate a little bit in some "forwards" direction, you see them all fall out of sync: the ones ahead of you tick a little faster the further they are from you; the ones behind you tick a little slower the further they are from you.

These *little desynchronicities* eventually build up into bigger effects. When you then come to a new constant velocity, they will all be ticking the same speed when you correct for a Doppler shift, but they will also be hopelessly out-of-sync in your coordinates, and that ticking rate will seem a little slower than the rate that your own clocks tick. Even more strangely, the grid will seem to be a little closer-spaced in the direction you're travelling.

However, we can prove that this theory is totally mathematically consistent. The coordinate transforms that describe it are called **Lorentz transforms**, which include the *Lorentz boosts* that I just described, along with rotations of the 3 space coordinates into each other. It is not very hard at all to boost by $+v$ and then by $-v$ and you find out that these effects all undo each other nicely, so that there is one cohesive 4D picture underlying all of it.

If we want to do physics we need things which are *invariant under Lorentz transforms*. Our best analogy of a 3D vector $\vec a$ is a new quantity called a "4-vector" $a^\mu = (A, \vec a)$, made by tacking on another "time" component $A$: together they must transform just like the position 4-vectors $r^\mu = (ct, \vec r)$ transform, in other words, they also have to obey the Lorentz transforms.

The way that we achieve invariance with these is as follows: if you have another 4-vector $b^\mu = (B, \vec b)$, then their *scalar product* $a^\mu b_\mu = a_\mu b^\mu$ is the number $A B - \vec a\cdot\vec b,$ and this is a number which every observer agrees on.

## The role of proper time and the 4-velocity

A particle which is moving uniformly might be described as having a bunch of position vectors over time $\vec r(t) = \vec r_0 + \vec v~t.$ The corresponding four-vectors are $(ct, \vec r(t))$. In the 4D space they describe a *line* called that particle's **worldline**.

If we Lorentz-boost by velocity $\vec v$ then the particle will be at rest relative to us, at some 3-dimensional position $\vec r_0'.$ The worldline will be parallel with the time axis, and the points are $(c \tau, \vec r_0')$ for all $\tau$. This measurement of time is very important; it is called the "proper time" $\tau$, and it can be measured by anybody by using the scalar product: let's say you want to know the proper time between $r_a^\mu$ (which for you is time $t_a$) and $r_b^\mu$ (time $t_b$), and let the 4-displacement between them be $D^\mu = r_b^\mu - r_a^\mu;$ then even in your coordinates, $D^\mu D_\mu$ is $c^2 \tau^2.$ So for example, between times $0$ and $T$, the 4-displacement above looks like $(c~T, \vec v~T)$ and the proper time is $\tau = T \sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2}.$ We often write this complicated square root as $1/\gamma$ so that everyone sees $T = \gamma~\tau$ time pass between events, where $\tau$ is the proper time measured by someone whose coordinates say that both events happened in the same place.

The proper time is also the best way to *take a time derivative of a 4-vector* since everyone can agree on it. So everyone can agree on the scalar products of the 4-velocity $\frac{dr^\mu}{d\tau} = (\gamma c, \gamma~\vec v),$ while not everyone agrees on scalar products of other things.

## Interpretations of the time coordinate of the 4-velocity

The simplest interpretation is, "it's exactly what you need to make the 4-velocity have length $c.$" This is the interpretation offered by Timaeus above: the 4-velocity has a scalar product with itself of exactly $c^2$ (as it must: in one frame, the 4-displacement is $(c\tau,\vec 0)$ so the 4-velocity is $(c, 0)$...!), so if we divide by $c$ it is a 4D 'unit vector' pointing in the direction of the worldline.

Another interpretation given often in pop-physics shows is that it is somehow a "speed with which the particle is going through time." This is *very* shaky, as you can see by the fact that it grows as the velocity grows. (You might have instead expected it to shrink, but that's not what the $-$ sign in the scalar product tells us!)

Suppose you scatter a density of any conserved stuff, $\rho_0,$ through space, at rest in some reference frame. I'll call it "charge" but it could be anything. Multiply this by the 4-velocity to get $(\gamma\rho_0, \gamma\rho_0\vec v).$ This has a very simple interpretation: $\rho = \gamma\rho_0$ represents the perceived charge density in any other reference frame; it grows because relativistic length contraction is forcing some of this charge into a smaller space. The first component is therefore the charge-density seen; the second component is something called a *current density* $\vec J = \rho \vec v$: if you have a small surface of area $dA$ with normal vector $\hat n$, the flow of charge through that surface is $\vec J \cdot \hat n ~dA.$ So it represents a sort of (charge density, current density) field.

Finally, suppose you multiply by the rest mass of a particle, $m_0$. The usual understanding of the four-momentum $p^\mu = (\gamma~m_0~c,\;\gamma~m_0~\vec v)$ is that it represents the kinetic-plus-rest-mass energy and momentum of the particle in your reference frame, $p^\mu = (E/c, \vec p).$ In this interpretation, since $v^\mu v_\mu = c^2,$ we have that $p^\mu p_\mu = m_0^2 c^2 = E^2 / c^2 - p^2,$ normally written as $$E^2 = m_0^2 c^4 + |\vec p|^2 c^2.$$If $\vec p = 0$ then of course this just reduces to the famous rest mass expression $E = mc^2$, but it gets better: the time component being $E = \gamma m_0 c^2$ also can be Taylor-expanded for small velocities to give $E = mc^2 + \frac 12 m v^2 + \dots,$ so the lowest-order terms are "rest mass" and "classical kinetic energy" and the remaining terms are relativistic kinetic energy contributions.

If you don't believe me that this really is E = (constant + kinetic energy), then you should try to prove the analogue of the work-energy theorem, $\vec F_\text{net} \cdot \vec v = \frac{d}{dt} (\frac{1}{2} m v^2).$ The process is identical to the classical proof extended to the relativistic definitions: start with $F_\text{net}^\mu = \frac{dp^\mu}{d\tau} = m_0 \frac{dv^\mu}{d\tau}$ and then try to form $F^\mu v_\mu.$ The same "reverse chain-rule, halved" approach gives $\frac{d}{d\tau} \left(\frac 12 m_0 v^\mu v_\mu\right)$... only, we now know that $v^\mu v_\mu = c^2$ and the derivative of any constant is 0. So *actually* $F^\mu v_\mu = 0,$ and so the kinetic energy *is indeed* completely contained in the momentum 4-vector now.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I think of myself as still and you as traveling.  Your clock ticks once.  Over the course of that clock tick, I say that you've traveled (according to my rulers) distances $dx,dy$, and $dz$ in the $x,y$ and $z$ directions, and I say that $dt$ seconds have elapsed (according to my clock).  In my coordinates, your velocity vector is $(dx,dy,dz,dt)$.

Comment: Coundn't get your point dude

Comment: But then you need the unit vector pointing in the same direction as that tangent vector.

Comment: @Timaeus:  The interval between clock ticks is 1 as measured by the travler, and so is 1 as measured by any other observer.

Comment: I think you mean (dx,dy,dz,1) since the other guy's clock has ticked once. Also, the interval between clock ticks depends on the observer's velocity: it is not always one.